# Dryer not heating issue

Tags: dryer, troubleshooting

My dryer is not heating. I checked the safety switches, heater, etc and found them to be ok. One check I made surprised me: a voltage check on the incoming terminals found 120 vac on each side of neutral from both hot sides, but zero across where I expected 240vac. Both line fuses OK. Why???

Comment: Can you provide a link to the other question you're referencing? And model number of the dryer?

Comment: The dryer is a whirlpool LER8648LG0

Comment: Sounds like you do not have both hot legs, only one. In other words your two hot legs are connected to the same leg in the panel (black or red). Is the dryer fed with a 2 pole breaker?

Comment: It is a fuse box, not breaker. Yes both fuses are not blown - checked with my ohm meter.

Comment: I guess there could be an open wire somewhere

Comment: Just checked - there is 246 vac on the input side of the fuses. So there could be a break between the fuses and the dryer receptacle.

Comment: Can you provide photos of the wiring at the fusebox?

Comment: Try replacing both fuses. Fuses can be ok when checked with an ohm meter but open when a load is applied. You may also have a bad fuse box or fuse holder, a broken wire or loose wire connection.